# OperationalError at /liste/ - DJANGO

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

Codes:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from django.http import *
import sqlite3

def verileri_listele(request):

    vt = sqlite3.connect("/root/bot/v1/database.db")
    im = vt.cursor()
    im.execute("""SELECT * FROM kullanim""")
    veriler = im.fetchall()

    for i in veriler:
        return HttpResponse(i[0], i[1], i[2])
```

Page:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/9400322/

Page ss:

[image: ss]

use django and python2

Comment: Please read this [Django NewbieMistakes](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/NewbieMistakes#DjangosaysUnabletoOpenDatabaseFilewhenusingSQLite3)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, check permissions on `/root/bot/v1/database.db` (it seems that root is owner of the file) and try to move it in another place. For example, with your python code (don't forget to change path in your code and set owner/permissions on database.db)

Also, even if you're will get working database, your code returns single row per request and it's would be problem. 
**Return of the HttpResponse object closes the connection.**
You must prepare full response text, and only then return **HttpResponse** object (only one).

Reading [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/) would be great for you!